# Copy SQL-Server Login Schema Problems

Tags: sql-server, database, database-schema

I'm trying to copy our application database from ServerA to ServerB and having issues with the LOGIN user SCHEMA.

**What I have done:**

- Detached DB on ServerA and copied MDF and LDF files to ServerB
- Attached new DB in SQL-Server on ServerB

Everything looks good except for the DB Owner login [fred] is not in the right SCHEMA [fred].

**ServerA CONFIG:** the **Security** > **Logins** shows [fred] as:

- Member of these roles: [sysadmin], [securityadmin], [dbcreator]
- Under 'User Mappings':

  - Database: [FredsDB]
  - User: [fred]
  - Default Schema: [fred]

**ServerB CONFIG:** the **Security** > **Logins** shows [fred] as:

- Member of these roles: [sysadmin], [securityadmin], [dbcreator]
- Under 'User Mappings':

  - Database: **He has no mapped database**

**To match ServerB to ServerA I try setting the following:**

- Map the [fred] login to [FredsDB]
- User [fred]
- Schema [fred]

**I get this error when trying to save changes on ServerB:**

> User, group, or role 'fred' already exists in the current database.

I can't get around this no matter what I try.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because the SIDs do not match anymore (due to orphaned users).  Not sure what steps you tried, but when moving databases between servers, i would first reference MSFT's [KB article 314546](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/314546) - How to move databases between computers running SQL Server.  There is a section that talks specifically about dealing with orphaned users.

Since your issue is with dbowner, I will take a wild guess that the following TSQL should resolve it:

```
exec sp_changedbowner 'sa' -- first change to a known/existing user
exec sp_changedbowner '[insert new owner name here]' -- now change to new owner
```